# How to Implement Activation Functions using OpenCV's Android API?

Tags: android, opencv, neural-network

I am an OpenCV and Android development noob and I am trying to implement neural networks using OpenCV's Java API. I have found all the functions I need except the ReLU activation function. So I decided to implement this function manually in Java. My implementation traverses the elements of Mat one by one, uses Mat.get() to access the element, modifies the negative values, and writes them back using Mat.put().

```
for (int i = 0; i < output_dim; i++) {
    float[] value = new float[1];
    input.get(0, i, value);
    if (value[0] < 0) {
        value[0] = 0;
        input.put(0, i, value);
    }
}
```

I have profiled my code and it looks like my ReLU function (get and put) is the bottleneck of the whole network operations. I can think of a few solutions, but I am not sure which one is better, or if there are solutions better than mine.

1. Use a parallel implementation of ReLU to process multiple inputs at a time.
2. Implement ReLU in C++ to have easier access to the elements of matrix.
3. Somehow use [OpenCV's DNN module](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html) or [ANN_MLP](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html) that have some of the basic building blocks for neural networks. Though I'm not sure how I can use these C++ implementations in my Java code.

Can you please let me know if any of these solutions is good or introduce other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified the above code and gained a huge speedup. The new code snippet looks like this:

```
float[] values = new float[output_dim];
input.get(0, 0, values);

for (int i = 0; i < output_dim; i++) {
    if (values[i] < 0) {
        value[i] = 0;
    }
}

input.put(0, 0, values);
```

It seems that accessing individual elements from Java takes a lot of time.